# How do I fix this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  avg(con_hits) as avg_hits 
FROM 
  content 
WHERE 
  con_type = 1 
  AND con_posttime < $twelve_hrs_ago 
  AND con_refresh = 0 
ORDER BY 
  con_posttime DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

I would like it to go to the first record that was posted at least 12 hours ago (denoted by the `$twelve_hrs_ago` variable which has the suitable timestamp), and take the average of the `con_hits` column, for the next 100 records. In my example, it disregards the `LIMIT`, and takes the average of every record in the table.

Is there a way to bypass that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`LIMIT` is applied to the resultset, after `AVG` is calculated. You can do what you want, with a subselect:

```
SELECT avg(con_hits) as avg_hits
FROM (
  SELECT con_hits
  FROM content
  WHERE
    con_type = 1
    AND con_posttime < $twelve_hrs_ago
    AND con_refresh = 0
  ORDER BY con_posttime DESC
  LIMIT 100
) x;
```

You can use the database to calculate the time offset too. Replace `$twelve_hrs_ago` above with:

```
date_add(now(), interval -12 hour)
```

Comment: Perfect! In your 2nd suggestion, using the code you provided results in avg_hits being NULL.

And whats the point of that x in the end?

Comment: In my opinion. It would be more readable to use date_sub instead. The function name denotes the purpose.

Comment: The x at the end is required because you must give a correlation name (i.e. a table alias) to any derived query in the FROM clause.

Comment: With the optional "AS" keyword the purpose becomes more clear: "SELECT avg(x.Foo) FROM (SELECT Foo FROM Table) AS x"

Comment: @J.J.: DATE_SUB() is MySQL centric, whereas DATE_ADD() should work everywhere.

Comment: @Yegor: I assumed that `con_posttime` is a datetime type; Maybe you used something else (Such as a timestamp)? In that case, you have to convert appropriately.

Comment: hm .. I just tested, and a timestamp works. Maybe your database server's clock is out of sync?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT avg(con_hits) as avg_hits FROM (
    SELECT con_hits FROM content 
    WHERE con_type = 1 AND con_posttime < $twelve_hrs_ago AND con_refresh = 0
    ORDER BY con_posttime DESC
    LIMIT 100
    )
```

Mysql supports subqueries, so this might do it for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html